# Check remaining width and resize DIV

Tags: jquery, resize, height, width

i found a few posts in here with a similar problem, but none of the solutions could really help me. now that's what i got:

> > my fullscreen is divided in two DIVs. 
> >     DIV#image_B shows an image at full HEIGHT: 100% and FLOAT:RIGHT
> >
> > now, whatever width that image has at full height >> i wish to fill up the DIV#imageA with the remaining WIDTH and have another image in there.

i can't get this done! :)

pleas help. thank you so much!

```
<div id="homepage_half">

<div id="homepage_left">resizetofullwidthplease</div>

<div id="homepage_right">
<img src="http://www.feierliste.de/assets/img/flyer/large/20130914T90.jpg" style="height:100%">
</div>

</div>

#homepage_right{
float: right;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
height: 50%;
```

}

```
#homepage_left{
float: left;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you possibly post here relevant parts of the code [you already have](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Also, feel free to post the relevant link here as well.

Comment: just edited the code i got. hope thats helps :) thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe giving div B position absolute and Div A as relative would solve ur prob..

Comment: thanks for your help. unfortunately that did not help. DIV A now hides between DIV B at full width ;(